# Debug bazel-based C++ project under VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, bazel

I'm trying to use Bazel [the Examples to build C++ code](https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/master/cpp-tutorial) to build and debug. I'm using [the Visual code editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to do so.

Withing the Bazel build targets I have the project build targets

[image]

where I execute build target for (right-click to build the *hello-world* target). When I start to debug the project I can't stop at the breakpoint line and it is executed throughly.

Here is my *launch.json*

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "c:\\bazel\\examples\\cpp-tutorial\\stage1\\bazel-bin\\main\\hello-world.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can set the project into the debug mode and stop at breakpoint code-line?

Comment: How do you build your target? Do you include debug symbols (`-c dbg` in the bazel command line arguments)? Then it should work, your `launch.json` looks fine.

Comment: oh well, I'm just using `bazelbuild.vscode-bazel` and have no `task.json` and `launch.json` files in the project ...

Comment: @user3428154 did you get it working? where does the `bazelbuild.vscode-bazel` file come from and what is it's content?